# At least $500$ of the $25,000$ students in a school come from the same state

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Imagine, in the school there are 25,000 students, at least one from each of 50 states. Than must be a group of 500 students coming from same state.

I don't know what to count the 25,000 students or 500 students.

**Question** How can I prove the pigenhole principle in this case?

**Attempt** I know, If $k$ is a positive integer and $k+1$ or more objects are placed into $k$ boxes , than there is at least one box containing two or more of the objects. I don't know what to count the 25,000 students or 500 students ?

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: How can I prove the pigenhole principle in this case?

Comment: This question will probably be closed soon, like your two other questions.  Why not try following the suggestions: *Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.*

Comment: I know, If k is a positive integer and k+1 or more objects are placed into k boxes , than there is at least one box containing two or more of the objects.

Comment: I don't know what to count the 25,000 students or 500 students ?

Comment: Very good, you should edit your question so that it contains your two comments above.

Comment: Students are objects.  Each state has $499$ boxes.

Comment: That's how my professor wrote the question. It is really confusing to me.

Comment: If each state had fewer than $500$ students, you'd be able to fit all its students into the boxes, one student per box.  But there are only ... boxes in all  ...

Comment: Common guys, easy whit the downvotes -7 is now excessive, she is clearly a new user and she have already put her work in the comments.@Betty I strongly recommend you to edit your question and add your first three comments there, that is how you avoid all the downvotes and avoid your question to be closed !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your understanding of the pigeonhole principle, you know that if there are 51 students, then there is at least one state with at least 2 students.

Similarly, if there are 101 students, then there is at least one state with at least 3 students.

If there were $50n+1$ students, then there is at least one state with at least $n+1$ students.

Can you do the rest?

Comment: I'm waiting for the answer. It is not clear to me.

Comment: Not yet. Can you write a little more?

Comment: If there were 24950 students, then it would be possible that no state has 500 students (this would be the case if each state has 499 students).  But if there were 24951 students ...

Comment: What is n? 500 students?

Comment: Yes, at least 1 state has 500 students if there were 24951 students.

Comment: Try n=499.  Don't be confused by the number 25,000.  Pretend that instead of 25,000 students, there were 24,951 students.  If that was the case, then at least 1 state has 500 students.  But adding more students (to make it 25,000) doesn't change the reasoning.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I understand now.

Comment: Very good.  Next time you ask a question, you should indicate what you know so that the people who answer your questions would be able to know where to start their explanations.

Comment: I have another question which is confusing. Can you answer for me?

Comment: Okay.  I'll see if I can answer it.  Post it as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the contrary: there are at most $499$ students from each state. Then, there are at most $499\times50$ students in total, which contradicts the fact that there are $25000$ students.

Comment: That sound good to me, thank you.

Comment: But you suppose to add 1 not subtract number 1.

Comment: @Betty What do you mean by "add 1 not subtract number 1"?